# wifi not working after upgrading to 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, gnome

these commands were run

wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && \
chmod +x wireless-info && \
./wireless-info

and the output is

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 06 Aug 2016 13:21 IST +0530

Booted last: 06 Aug 2016 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e074]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b404 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0489:e069 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

asus_nb_wmi            24576  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
snd_soc_rt5640        114688  0
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_core          212992  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_pcm               106496  7 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
wmi                    20480  1 asus_wmi
video                  40960  2 i915,asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.12  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF1]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1954 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2357 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:853819 (853.8 KB)  TX bytes:297251 (297.2 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      4209     1  0 13:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eth0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Auto Ethernet
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       c061eff9-db8f-49a4-92c3-45f5dcd35d45
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{7}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   c061eff9-db8f-49a4-92c3-45f5dcd35d45 | Auto Ethernet
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.12/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             202.88.131.90
IP4.DNS[2]:                             202.88.131.89
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 202.88.131.90 202.88.131.89
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.0.12
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        default_ip_ttl = 64
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       time_offset = 0
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 529200
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 302400
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       expiry = 1471074446
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       next_server = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 604800
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF1]>/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VIKAS]] (600 root)
[connection] id=VIKAS | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=VIKAS | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Hotspot | type=802-11-wireless | autoconnect=false
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Freelancer | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=shared
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TP-LINK_AA70]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TP-LINK_AA70 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=TP-LINK_AA70 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Jaguar]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Jaguar | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Jaguar | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ES_9035]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ES_9035 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=ES_9035 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Dont steal my wifi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Dont steal my wifi | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Dont steal my wifi | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/jaguarpaw]] (600 root)
[connection] id=jaguarpaw | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=jaguarpaw | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Watchers of the wall]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Watchers of the wall | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Watchers of the wall | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/mere karan arjun aaenge]] (600 root)
[connection] id=mere karan arjun aaenge | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=mere karan arjun aaenge | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BMsK-U01HNTMxRg 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BMsK-U01HNTMxRg 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=BMsK-U01HNTMxRg | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SHAILESH]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SHAILESH | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=SHAILESH | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Password kya hai?]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Password kya hai? | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Password kya hai? | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/skartik]] (600 root)
[connection] id=skartik | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=skartik | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BMsK-U01HNTMxRg]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BMsK-U01HNTMxRg | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=BMsK-U01HNTMxRg | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/DIRECT-pC-BRAVIA]] (600 root)
[connection] id=DIRECT-pC-BRAVIA | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=DIRECT-pC-BRAVIA | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AndroidAP]] (600 root)
[connection] id=AndroidAP | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=AndroidAP | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/UTTAM]] (600 root)
[connection] id=UTTAM | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=UTTAM | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/DIRECT-pC-BRAVIA-7a166355-dff0-4165-a66b-6e2f20d0dc5f]] (600 root)
[connection] id=DIRECT-pC-BRAVIA | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=DIRECT-pC-BRAVIA | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/I love my india]] (600 root)
[connection] id=I love my india | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=I love my india | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/YUREKA]] (600 root)
[connection] id=YUREKA | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=YUREKA | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/duggu]] (600 root)
[connection] id=duggu | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=duggu | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/virus]] (600 root)
[connection] id=virus | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=virus | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Jaguarpaw]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Jaguarpaw | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Jaguarpaw | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/skynet call 8800478722]] (600 root)
[connection] id=skynet call 8800478722 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=skynet call 8800478722 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/mt7630e.conf]
options mt7630e fwlps=N

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

[/etc/pm/sleep.d/00_check_touchpad_status] (755 root)
LOGFILE="/var/log/sleep.log"
case "$1" in
        resume|thaw)
                echo "Resumed normal from suspend at `date`" >> "$LOGFILE"
                /usr/bin/python3 /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/touchpad-indicator/share/touchpad-indicator/check_touchpad_status.py resume
                echo "Touchpad enabled"
                ;;
esac

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x14c3:0x7630 (mt7630e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```